# Reading Data from a text file using Batch

Tags: batch-file, input

I am trying to read a text file which contains an integer value [it might be anything between 0-20] , in case the value is 10 ,I want to execute some commands .

```
  FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,3) DO (
     Set /P Counter <"D:\WeeklyRun\Flag.txt" 
     if%Counter%==10(Run some command)
     if%Counter%!=10(timeout 20)
     )
```

I tried writing the following code ,but it did not work for me 
Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space after te if's and before the `(` and an `=` before the redirect `<` sign, also the `!=` must be

```
not expression ==
```

The `"` around the path must be removed otherwise the counter is not set which causes the error `( is unexpected`, in order to cope with that you need to put `'` aroung both sides of your camparison.

Here your reworked sample

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,3) DO (
  Set /p Counter=< c:\WeeklyRun\Flag.txt
  if "%Counter%"=="10" (
    echo Run some command
  ) 
  if not "%Counter%"=="10" (echo timeout 20)
)
```

Comment: if %Counter%==1(echo ct)  ,

Comment: add space before your (
see my sample, in such cases comment out all the libnes and start uncommenting them one by one until you encounter the error, batch unfortunatly doesn't say on which line the errro is and sometimes you have no clue

Comment: It says cannot find file ,do I need to place the batch file in the same folder as the file Flag.txt ?

Comment: think not if the path is correct, but that is what I did to test and it worked, try my sample with .\flag.txt, the " are not necessary if there are no spaces in the path

Comment: I copied the exact code ,its says "  ( was unexpected at this time "   :(  is there something that I am missing here ?

Comment: I added the cause of that to my answer, i tested this earlier but not with your path, if you create the file in the path my adpated sample should run correctly

Comment: The path is the same D-> WeeklyRun -> Flag.txt

Comment: I can't say more than this sample is working on my system, so if your path is without " around it and the file is present it should work

Comment: I stromgly recommend to use `"` rather than `'` for the `if’ comparisons to avoid trouble with spaces or other special characters...

Comment: @aschipfl I never had trouble with `'` but I belive you so I adapted the answer, Thnx

Comment: @peter: try `if 'a b' == 'a b' echo yes`

Comment: @aschipfl indeed, good thing I never used spaces in values then, my batch is rusty I'm afraid, almost 95% of the time having fun with Ruby these days, Thnx again

Comment: but sometimes when i am running the code ,when the value in the file is getting updated while the for loop is running ,it still take the old value ,is there any command to clear cache ,or something like that so that it captures the updated value every time.

Comment: the file is read for every number in your enumeration (1 , 1, 3) in your example and should reflect changes, it seems to me your goal would better be achieved by a real script in some easy programming language such as eg Ruby.
But I believe your question is answered with great extend, so could you please accept the answer and upvote ?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers ,it did help me get some clarity ,but then i decided to write the whole thing in Java ,that worked out better for me ,@peter thanks for the suggestions .

Comment: you are welcome, such things are not really java's strength tough, I could give you a Ruby solution in one line